# AWS-EMR-S3DISTCP - Does aws charges for s3 actions?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-emr, s3distcp, aws-billing

I was looking into the documentation of **s3distcp** (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html) but I was not able to find any explicit site where mention about costs of each action. This is a sample scenario:

1. I have a bucket with **10,000** objects.
2. An EMR cluster with 3 instances will be used to execute **s3distcp**.
3. **s3distcp** has *--deleteOnSuccess* option enabled.
4. Source and destination bucket, along with the EMR, **are on the same account and region.**

Questions is:

1. Apart of the EMR usage (based on instance type, elapsed time, etc), is there an additional cost for s3 actions (ie. if I moved all 10K objects, does it mean 10K COPY requests)? Or billing will be associated only with the EMR costs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS S3 costs will be billed as separate line items from your AWS EMR costs, so you should factor in S3 costs in addition to the EMR charges. S3 costs in this scenario will include charges for *requests* and possibly *data transfer* as per the [S3 pricing guide](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/).

That said, the associated S3 charges are likely to be trivial relative to the cost of an EMR cluster.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I saw that documentation site, but still is not clear in some scenarios. Let's assume this: I've a notebook (on emr, same region, same account) that the only thing that it does is get a list of the top 10 objects. Based on `spark` loads on memory the input (1K objects), every time that this piece of code runs, we are charged 10K requests? I really don't think so.

Comment: I don't know the specifics of what your notebook is doing so it's hard to comment on the scenario but you will be charged for any and all requests made to the S3 service, however many that is.

Comment: Don't worry, I just wanted to explain a similar scenario. I understand the part of the requests done through cli or any other external resource such as postman, web app, etc. but when we run, in this case the map reduce job, I realized that it internally does a temp copy on hdfs (within emr) and then move it to the dest bucket. The concern is that, this tool is recommended directly on aws site for large amount of data transfer, so it doesn't really makes sense to be charged (or at least in the same way) as a simple script with that behavior. I really appreciate your feedback and your comments